# CakePHP pages_controller always uses default layout

Tags: cakephp, layout, default

I have a static page that I want to serve so I made a .ctp in the /views/pages/ directory. The problem is that it's using the default layout which I do not want to use. I tried making my own pages_controller and passing the $layout var but that does not work. There has to be a way to tell a /pages/ to use another layout.ctp. No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few things to check

- make a custom pages_controller.php
- define variable $layout and set it to the layout you want.
- make sure the layout exists in
  views/layout/

Comment: I set $this->layout = 'xxx'; in the display function on app/controllers/pages_controller, right?

Comment: Yes, that's how you do it.  Is that pages controller the one being loaded?  Check by making a function in it to output something simple, and try to load that url (eg make PagesController::test(), and try to access /pages/test)

Comment: Yes, I've been trying that and no avail. It's not passing anything. Everything I had read said that I just place an /app/controllers/pages_controller.php and it would be set. Is there another switch to flip?

Comment: check route.php in config folder. see if it's rerouted to somewhere else.

Comment: It's def an issue with my beforeFilter() in my app_controller. I think it's not allowing me to pass any set(var) without authenticating first.

Comment: Can't believe no answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue, thought i'd report my solution in case others are facing the same thing.

I wasn't using pages, but had a controller "members":

```
<?php
class MembersController extends AppController {

    var $name       = 'Members';
    var $helpers    = array('Html','Javascript','Form','Time');
    var $uses       = array();  

    function index() {
        // Works, will load the ajax.ctp layout
        // http://localhost/members/index
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
    }


    function signup() {
        // Does not work, loads the default.ctp layout
        //http://localhost/members/signup
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
    }

}
?>
```

function index() was properly loading the ajax layout, but signup() kept loading default. **Turns out the mistake was I did not have a view/signup.ctp**. Once I added that it loaded the proper layout. Was an absentminded mistake but left me barking up the wrong tree because signs were pointing towards a layout issue rather than a view issue.

Answer (score 0):

### goes to the following link "**lib\Cake\Controller**" open CakeErrorController.php add your layout .

```
public function __construct($request = null, $response = null) {
        parent::__construct($request, $response);
        $this->constructClasses();
        $this->Components->trigger('initialize', array(&$this));
        $this->_set(array('cacheAction' => false, 'viewPath' => 'Errors'));
        $this->layout='student';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and all errors were misleading.
What my problem ended up being is that I was trying to use a controller that didn't have a backing table/model so I was trying to reuse some other name in the controller's $name member variable because otherwise it would say that model didn't exist.
Long story short make sure that your controller name has a backing model object with the same naming convention.